# How to hide headers in bootstrap subtables

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I am trying to customize the code in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dabros/vuLj1bcb/

```
var $table = $('#table');
$(function() {

 $table.bootstrapTable({
columns: [{
  field: 'col1',
  title: 'Col1'
}, {
  field: 'col2',
  title: 'Col2'
}],
data: data,
detailView: true,
onExpandRow: function(index, row, $detail) {
  console.log(row)
  $detail.html('<table></table>').find('table').bootstrapTable({
    columns: [{
      field: 'col3',
      title: 'Col3'
    }, {
      field: 'col4',
      title: 'Col4'
    }, {
      field: 'col5',
      title: 'Col5'
    }],
    data: row.nested,
    // Simple contextual, assumes all entries have further nesting
    // Just shows example of how you might differentiate some rows, though also remember row class and similar possible flags
    detailView: row.nested[0]['other'] !== undefined,
    onExpandRow: function(indexb, rowb, $detailb) {
      $detailb.html('<table></table>').find('table').bootstrapTable({
        columns: [{
          field: 'col6',
          title: 'Col6'
        }, {
          field: 'col7',
          title: 'Col7'
        }],
        data: rowb.other
          });
        }
      });

   }
  });
});
```

so that the headers of the subtables are not shown. It is clear I have to use something like 'display:none' for the headers but I am not getting where to make the changes. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation :
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/
There is an option `showHeader` that you can set to false
The table options are defined in `jQuery.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults`

Since you may want to use their CDN, You can add a `display: none` on the `thead` element of the table